# What is Range of $x^3 -\ cos(1/x)$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, education

What is the range of $x^3 - \cos\frac{1}{x}?$

Comment: What do _you_ think? And why do you think that?

Comment: What's the limit of $\cos \frac{1}{x}$, to infinity and negative infinity? How does it affect the $x^3$ term, if it does at all?

Comment: It's difficult for me to identify the range for this, for i know the range of x^3 and of cos(1/x), but i am having trouble understanding what it will be when both those functions are combined together.

Answer (score 3):

I think you are confused by this part,$$\cos{\frac{1}{x}}$$ This is even function oscillating between [-1, 1].

The function graph looks like:
http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=cos(1%2Fx)

Comment: Yes, I know what this graph looks like. When I computed the new function, which is defined as f(x)= x^3 - cos(1/x), the graph was oscillating and unreadable. Therefore, I wasn't able to deduce the range of the function.

Answer (score 1):

I think what @shenlei was saying is correct. If you are indeed confused about the range of $\cos(\frac{1}{x}),$ then consider that $-1\leq \cos(\frac{1}{x})\leq 1,$ for all $x\ne 0.$

If you'd like to see if a number, say $b$, is in the range of the function $f(x)=x^3,$ then you can consider $x=\sqrt[3]{b},$ so $$f(\sqrt[3]{b})=(\sqrt[3]{b})^3=b,$$ and thus $x^3$ is onto, its range is all of the real numbers $\Bbb{R},$ and is called **onto**.

Finally, you should ask yourself, what happens to $$x^3-\cos\left(\frac{1}{x}\right),$$ then? Well, you should try to rationalize that $x^3$ having a range of all real numbers indicates that $x^3-\cos\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$ has the same range.